# Rewards for Operations

Tags: protocol, operation, rewards, fee

Out of these Operations which operations affect the balance of an Account either by rewards or by any transaction?

First four I know they incur a fee at least so that balance gets affected. Can any one help me with other operation?

- Transaction
- Revelation
- Origination
- Delegation
- Endorsement
- Seed_nonce_revelation
- Double_endorsement_evidence
- Double_baking_evidence
- Activate_account
- Proposals
- Ballot

Answer (score 3):

Here is a short description of how operations can affect balance:

- Transaction - `transfer | fee`
- Revelation - `fee`
- Origination - `transfer | fee`
- Delegation - `fee`
- Endorsement - `reward`
- Seed_nonce_revelation - `reward`
- Double_endorsement_evidence - `reward | loss`
- Double_baking_evidence - `reward | loss`
- Activate_account - `income`

---

- Proposals - doesn't affect
- Ballot - doesn't affect

Comment: Thanks for the response . I would verify and get back

Comment: Could you please add a link that can be used to check/explore your answer deeper ? Thank you!

Comment: I don't have such a link unfortunately... All of that is my own experience gained when creating the Tezos blockchain indexer https://github.com/baking-bad/tzkt

Answer (score 0):

All of those can affect the balance of an account either directly or indirectly. Some of those incur burn fees, or transaction fees, which are subtracted from balance. The double_* are punishment for those who injected a double, and reward for those that baked the evidence.